# How to add texture in Vpython?

Tags: python, vpython

**i Wonder How to  put texture on my boxes in my Vpython script?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from visual import *

box(pos=(-1,-1,-2), length=2, height=2, width=4, material=materials.wood)
```

[image]

For more details, see http://vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/materials.html

**Edit:** at the link above, look for the section titled "Making a texture from a photo"

**Edit2:** not sure what's causing your error; this works for me:

```
from visual import *
import Image

im = Image.open('flower.jpg')  # size must be power of 2, ie 128 x 128
tex = materials.texture(data=im, mapping='rectangular')

box(material=tex)
```

[image]

**Edit3:** I figured out what caused your error:

```
box(material=materials.loadTGA(filename))
```

fails;

```
tex = materials.texture(data=loadTGA(filename), mapping='rectangular')
box(material=tex)
```

works properly.

Comment: yeh but want to add own image as texture ?

Comment: How to get the texture on all sides off the box ? only get a stretched image :/